# Время на ознакомление с Visual Studio C++

Tags: visual-studio, ide

Сколько времени нужно потратить, чтобы научиться уверенно работать в Visual Studio C++?

Comment: Много. Но зависит от Ваших способностей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут много факторов: уже имеющаяся подготовка и опыт программирования, способности, желание, наличие времени, личностные качества (лень, внимательность и т.д.) Так - от нескольких месяцев до ...   Если хотите научиться чему-то, не думайте о времени, сосредоточьтесь на процессе и получайте удовольствие.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за такие ответы!

Comment: Если помогло - поставьте галочку

Answer (score 1):

Начать "просто работать" и собирать проекты можно достаточно быстро, *т.к интерфейс все-таки интуитивен.*

А дальше - поскольку "уверенная работа" - это прежде всего, быстрое выполнение рутинных задач, то рекомендую начать привыкать использовать горячие клавишы.

Удобные `cheat list'ы` можно найти [**здесь**](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/visual-studio-2010-allinone-for-dummies-cheat-shee.html) и [**здесь.**](http://devcheatsheet.com/tag/visual-studio/).

Comment: А какое время может уйти на изучение самого языка? Чтобы освоить его и можно было работать в этой сфере?

Comment: <a href=http://demotivators.ru/posters/205552/uchim-c-za-21-den.htm>21 день =)</a>